# Proper way for absolutely positioned footer

Tags: css, position

I positioned my footer at the bottom of the page with

```
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
```

but for pages that are too "low" (the `height` of the `html` is small) there's room between the footer and the bottom of the window. I fixed it by setting `min-height` for the `html` element in pixels which I think is an **ugly solution**. A percentage wouldn't work here. Ideally, the `min-height` for the `html` should be the window height I guess. I could probably fix that with Javascript but that seems overly complicated too.

So I removed `body{position:relative;}` to position the footer absolutely to the window but that's even much worse for "high" pages. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RubenGeert/vZqF8/) for the effect.

***Is there a more elegant alternative?*** I do **not** want to use `position:fixed;` because this will cause the footer to be always visible which I find a waste of window space in most cases. If anybody has a suggestion, please feel free to edit the fiddle.

Comment: [**Sticky Footer**](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/) - Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: I don't get it... if you don't want it fixed, why don't you just put it at the end?

Comment: @Ruddy: yeah, that's the desired effect. I do feel the `.page-wrap` is not very semantic and the whole thing requires quite some CSS.

Comment: @RubenGeert Its the best way to do it as far as I know. Its that much that needs adding.

Comment: @Ruddy: I think I found a better one. See below.

Comment: @RubenGeert This will cover up the bottom part of the page. [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/WyJa7/2/) The last `test` text should be in red, but you cant see it because its behind the nav.

Comment: @Ruddy: good catch. Can't we fix that with some `padding` or `margin`?

Comment: @RubenGeert Your on a roll, was a good idea what you tried so why stop now? Give it ago and find out :D

Comment: @Ruddy: I **am** giving it a go ;-)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51664/discussion-between-ruddy-and-rubengeert)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the suggestions, they put me on the right track. I think the trick is

```
html{
    height:100%;
}

body{
    position:relative;
    min-height:100%;
}
```

This achieves the desired effect **without non semantic `.wrapper div's`**. See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/RubenGeert/WyJa7/1/) for a demo.

In some cases some `padding-bottom` on the element before the footer will be required in order not to have it obscured by the footer.

**UPDATE**

I think I found the [final solution](http://jsfiddle.net/RubenGeert/WyJa7/9/):

```
body{
margin-bottom:50px;
}
```

combined with

```
.footer{
position:absolute;
bottom:-50px;
}
```

will create space and a margin for all content before the footer with clean CSS and semantic markup.

Comment: +1 I was about to give the same answer (here's a more readable demo:) **http://jsbin.com/jahug/1/edit**

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Doesn't work, read my comments on the question. Here is your demo also not working [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/gomokufo/1/), close but doesn't work.

Comment: Setting some `padding-bottom` on the last element before the footer will [fix it](http://jsfiddle.net/RubenGeert/WyJa7/8/). That may in some cases raise new complications. It kinda depends on the styling of this last element whether this fix is a good solution.

Comment: @RubenGeert The best option that I see, is go with the sticky footer.

Comment: I think both the markup and CSS of the sticky footer are not very clean or semantic. I think I really do prefer the tiny `padding-bottom` "hack". If Javascript is enabled it's super easy to get the element before the footer with jQuery's `prev()` method too and apply the padding with `css('padding','3em');` or something.

Comment: @RubenGeert Seems like a lot of effort to me but whatever works for you. Hope I helped a little, happy coding!

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan That last span is `height: 70px;` you can see like `10px` of it.

Comment: @Ruddy you're right here's a fix that I forgot to add. I had only the padding to compensate header , now logically added also to compensate footer: http://jsbin.com/jahug/2/edit Nothing easier.

Comment: @RubenGeert my mistake I forgot to compensate with padding the footer height. Clearly visible now in my last demo http://jsbin.com/jahug/2/edit

Answer (score 0):

Wrap both the `ul` list with a parent `div` and make it height:100%;

And there is no necessity of `top:0` for header.

```
.footer{
  bottom:0;
  position:absolute;
}
```

**[Updated DEMO](http://jsbin.com/conilohe/2/)**

Comment: OP said that 1200 is ugly and footer should: 1: be at the bottom if there's not much content in the page; 2: If there's lot of content - stay below that content.

Comment: You edit is not good, look what happens if there's lot of content http://jsbin.com/conilohe/3/edit

Comment: Isn't there a way to avoid the non semantic `.wrapper` div's?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use footer at bottom layout. try my example code

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div class="w1">
            <p>content of the page</p>
            <p>content of the page</p>
            <p>content of the page</p>
            <p>content of the page last</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">footer content</div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
html,
body{
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
}
#wrapper{
    background:#000;
    min-height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.w1{
    background:#f00;
    padding-bottom:50px; /* footer height */
}
#footer{
    background:#ff0;
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    margin-top:-50px; /* footer height */
}
```